# Unable to deploy emissary-ingress in local kubernetes cluster. Fails with `error validating data: ValidationError(CustomResourceDefinition.spec)`

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, ambassador

I'm trying to install emissary-ingress using the [instructions here](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/emissary/latest/topics/install/install-ambassador-oss/).

It started failing with error `no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta"`. I searched and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054743/4980703) on Stack Overflow which said to update `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1` to `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1` which I did.
It also asked to use the `admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1` which my kubectl already uses.

When I run the `kubectl apply -f filename.yml` command, the above error was gone and a new error started popping in with error: `error validating data: ValidationError(CustomResourceDefinition.spec): unknown field "validation" in io.k8s.apiextensions-apiserver.pkg.apis.apiextensions.v1.CustomResourceDefinitionSpec;`

What should I do next?

My kubectl version - Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.4", GitCommit:"3cce4a82b44f032d0cd1a1790e6d2f5a55d20aae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-11T18:16:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.2", GitCommit:"8b5a19147530eaac9476b0ab82980b4088bbc1b2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:32:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

minikube version - minikube version: v1.23.2
commit: 0a0ad764652082477c00d51d2475284b5d39ceed

EDIT:

The custom resource definition yml file: [here](https://www.getambassador.io/yaml/ambassador/ambassador-crds.yaml)

The rbac yml file: [here](https://www.getambassador.io/yaml/ambassador/ambassador-rbac.yaml)

Comment: Can you please share you YAML file to take a look into it?

Comment: @VicenteAyala have edited the post to put the links to yml

Comment: thanks for sharing your YAML files. I have reviewed them searching for syntax errors and I didnt find anyone but what i found is when you use `---` in your yaml file and when it compiles, the engine interpret as a new deployment document within the same yaml file.

Comment: The yaml documents are separated by `---`, and if any stream (e.g. a file) contains more than one document then you should use the yaml.load_all function rather than yaml.load. The code:

`import yaml`

`stream = open("test", "r") docs = yaml.load_all(stream) for doc in docs:   for k,v in doc.items(): print k, "->", v    print "\n",`

Here you can check this post regarding your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359557/reading-yaml-file-with-python-results-in-yaml-composer-composererror-expected-a

Comment: These yaml files are provided by the emissary-ingress. I'm not generating them. So the separation into different deployments must be intentional.

Answer (score 2):

The `validation` field was officially deprecated in [apiextensions.k8s.io/v1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#customresourcedefinition-v122).
According to the official kubernetes documentation, you should use `schema` as a substitution for `validation.`
Here is a SAMPLE code using `schema` instead of `validation:`

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: crontabs.stable.example.com
spec:
  group: stable.example.com
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
--->  schema:  <---
        # openAPIV3Schema is the schema for validating custom objects.
        openAPIV3Schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            spec:
              type: object
              properties:
                cronSpec:
                  type: string
                  pattern: '^(\d+|\*)(/\d+)?(\s+(\d+|\*)(/\d+)?){4}$'
                image:
                  type: string
                replicas:
                  type: integer
                  minimum: 1
                  maximum: 10
```