# dask-getway on K8s using helm3: Error: failed to install CRD crds/daskclusters.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, dask, helm3, dask-kubernetes

I'm following the [instructions](https://gateway.dask.org/install-kube.html) to setup Dask on K8s Cluster. I'm on MacOS, have K8s running on Docker Desktop, `kubectl` version `1.22.5` and `helm` version `3.8.0`. After adding the repository, downloading default configuration, installing helm chart using command

```
RELEASE=my-dask-gateway
NAMESPACE=dask-gateway
VERSION=0.9.0

helm upgrade --install \
    --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --version $VERSION \
    --values path/to/your/config.yaml \
    $RELEASE \
    dask/dask-gateway
```

generates following output/error

```
"dask" already exists with the same configuration, skipping
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "dmwm-bigdata" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "dask" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Release "my-dask-gateway" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: failed to install CRD crds/daskclusters.yaml: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

An older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054622/unable-to-install-crds-in-kubernetes-kind) suggests to either update the manifest or use older version of kubernetes. Does that mean dask is not compatible with recent versions of kubernetes?

Comment: This is fixed in the repo main. You could grab the CRDs from there, or wait for a release, which we are hoping to do soon. Otherwise, yes, you would need an older version of kubernetes for dask-gateway to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Posting community wiki answer for better visibility:**

This is fixed in the repo main. You could grab the CRDs from there, or wait for a release, which we are hoping to do soon. Otherwise, yes, you would need an older version of kubernetes for dask-gateway to work.